# Button state change when navigate pages in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

In a list of products, there is an "Add to cart" button for each product, a single product must be in the cart client cannot add the same item again cart. When I click the button it gets disabled, but if navigate between page then button state became active again.

**Html**

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm mt-2" type="button"
                (click)="btnAddToCart(prod)" [disabled]="itemExists.includes(prod.Id)">
          Add To Cart
</button>
```

**component**

```
itemExists: number[] = [];

btnAddToCart(product: ProductList) {
  this.cartService.addToCart(product);
  if (product.Id && !this.itemExists.includes(product.Id)) {
     this.itemExists.push(product.Id);
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using ngOnInit or a constructor?

Comment: Yeah... possibility that the prod.Id doesn't exist yet.  Are you using state management like NGRx or anything?

Comment: My assumption is that the component gets re-created, and the `itemExists` array is getting re-initialised. You need to find a more persistent place to keep track of the items that you have in the cart, like a singleton service, or a service provided high enough in the hierarchy.

Comment: I didn't initialize itemExists  in constructor or ngOnInit

Answer (score 0):

do the test on your cartService instead of itemExists.

you must use a singleton service, add an @Injectable annotation to your service like that :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class CartService{
}
```

Your itemExists is not share between your pages but a singleton service yes.

Comment: can u give me a sample. I'm new to angular

Comment: You change your cartService like above, and your [disable] property of the button to your list in cartService, like [disabled]="cartService.yourlistitem.include(prod.id)" and delete : if (product.Id && !this.itemExists.includes(product.Id)) {
     this.itemExists.push(product.Id);
  }